# What is the most efficient way to grab a rectangle of pixels in ios?

Tags: ios, uiimage, pixel

I have the following code that is attempting to test each pixel in a rectangle of pixels

px, py = Location of touch
dx, dy = Size of rectangle to be tested

```
UIImage *myImage; // image from which pixels are read
int ux = px + dx;
int uy = py + dy;
for (int x = (px-dx); x <= ux; ++x)
{
    for (int y = (py-dy); y <= uy; ++y)
    {
        unsigned char pixelData[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
        CGImageRef cgimage = myImage.CGImage;
        int imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(cgimage);
        int imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(cgimage);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-px, py - imageHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight), cgimage);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(context);

        // Here I have latest pixel, with RBG values stored in pixelData that I can test
    }
}
```

The code in the inner loop is grabbing the pixel at location x, y. Is there a more efficient way to grab the entire rectangle of pixels from (x-dx,y-dy), (x+dx,y+dy) from the UIImage (myImage)?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, your answer is simple.

The problem is that you're creating a whole new bitmap context **for every single pixel** you scan. Creating just one bitmap context is expensive, and doing that thousands of times in succession is really bad for performance.

Just create one single bitmap context (with a custom data object) at first, and then scan through that data. It'll be way faster.

```
UIImage *myImage; // image from which pixels are read
CGSize imageSize = [myImage size];    

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageSize.width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

unsigned char *pixelData = (unsigned char*) calloc(imageSize.height * imageSize.width * bytesPerPixel, sizeof(unsigned char))
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, imageSize.width, 1imageSize.height bitsPerComponent, bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height), myImage.CGImage);

// you can tweak these 2 for-loops to get whichever section of pixels from the image you want for reading.

for (NSInteger x = 0; x < imageSize.width; x++) {

  for (NSInteger y = 0; y < imageSize.height; y++) {

       int pixelIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;

       CGFloat red   = (pixelData[pixelIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
       CGFloat green = (pixelData[pixelIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
       CGFloat blue  = (pixelData[pixelIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
       CGFloat alpha = (pixelData[pixelIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
       pixelIndex += 4;

       UIColor *yourPixelColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

    }
  }
}

// be a good memory citizen
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
free(pixelData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and explanation, but i don't see any place where you write the image into the context?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. It's fixed now.